# Creating toast on onItemSelected from spinner item. Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I was trying to add the toast to my application activity such that when item is selected from spinner the selected items name popped us on toast here's my code for on Item selected.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state_spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    String state = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

logcat data

```
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not forget to call `show()` method on your toast -  like this:

```
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Literally copied the other guy's answer. I do not like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (you forgot to add `show()` at the end):

```
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: An answer is more useful if you explain **why** some code should be tried.

Comment: its just for testing the spinner text is selected or not, and its not working. I've added some logcat logs in question. please check.